# Adding UISearchBar programatically - Bar is Off Screen at Launch - iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, search

I have added a UISearchBar to a table in my iPad app using the below code. The table is on the left hand side of my split view controller.

The problem is that when the app starts the search bar is strangely off screen to the left - you can just see the last few pixels of it. If you click on it, or scroll down and back up, it reverts itself and looks like it should.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this ?

Thanks

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                    initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                    contentsController:self];

searchBar.delegate = self;
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource=self;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create the UISearchBar with a frame like:

```
 CGRect searchViewFrame = CGRectMake(33, 33, 264, 31);
```

or whatever dimensions or origin.

Like other resource, you can create the UISearchBar within a UIView, and add this UIView to the UITableView:

```
UIView *containerSearch = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: searchViewFrame];
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[containerSearch addSubview: searchBar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerSearch;
```